# Meaning of "Murder" in this context

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> Gringoire followed Esmeralda and Djali
>   deeper and deeper into the maze of dark
>   streets. Esmeralda looked over her shoulder a
>   few times, suspicious that she was being
>   followed. Suddenly, Gringoire heard her
>   scream! He turned the shadowy corner and
>   saw her struggling with two men.
>   Gringoire advanced boldly. “Stop!” he
>   cried. Then he noticed that one of the men
>   was Quasimodo and the other one was the
>   Archdeacon Frollo. The hunchback struck
>   Gringoire and sent him reeling. Then
>   Quasimodo ran back and picked up the
>   young girl. He carried her gently—as if she
>   were a silken scarf. The other man followed,
>   and the goat ran after all three.
>   **“Murder! Murder! ”** Esmeralda cried out.
>   Some passing horsemen from the king’s
>   bodyguard heard her call. They jumped down
>   from their horses and snatched her from
>   Quasimodo.

Dose it mean: thuggee= to kill someone or here mean: just crying for help.

Answer (score 2):

In this context shouting "Murder!" is a cry designed to bring attention and help. Esmeralda may not literally think Quasimodo is going to kill her, but she doesn't want to be kidnapped.

Answer (score 0):

"Murder!" was at one time something that British and American people, when attacked or threatened, shouted to get attention from neighbours, bystanders or the police, even when no actual murder was being committed or likely. A fuller cry would be "Help! Police! Murder!".

> According to the story of Edward, the son, he was awakened at about
>   three o'clock by hearing his sister cry, "Help, police, murder." He
>   jumped out of bed and ran to the door,  when an electric light was
>   flashed in his eyes which almost blinded him, but he tried to catch
>   hold of something and caught a man around the neck. The man held a
>   flashlight in his right hand and fired a revolver from his left, the
>   bullet passing through the pajamas of Edward and stopping in the
>   bedclothes of his bed.

[Transcript of evidence in murder trial (1910, USA)](https://casetext.com/case/people-v-giro)